# Creating multiple permanent redirects to single node app route

Tags: node.js, networking, routes, digital-ocean, domain-name

I have a set of domain names for which I have to create permanent redirects to a single domain which is being used by a Node App running on a digital ocean server and let's say if it has 3 different routes like `/a, /b, /c` and I want my domains to point to `/a, /b, /c` respectively.

Also, what other info can I provide to make my question more clearer.

Comment: Are you using Express?

Comment: Yes, I am using Express 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but in your node.js app you could do something like:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    // remove the port number if it's there
    const host = req.get('host').split(':')[0]

    if(host === "a.com") {
        res.redirect('/a')
    }
    else if(host === "b.com") {
        res.redirect('/b')
    }
    else if(host === "c.com") {
        res.redirect('/c')
    }
    else {
        // redirect somewhere else
    }
})

app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello from a')
})

app.get('/b', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello from b')
})

app.get('/c', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello from c')
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on 3000')
})
```

You can test this locally by updating your hosts file, to point a.com, b.com and c.com to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I also thought of a similar solution but then I thought here redirects are based on request headers which can be altered by users / bots. Would that affect in any way here ? Also If let's say I have 5 domain names pointing to the same digital ocean droplet, now how do I write in express so that my whole app serves requests from one domain and the other domains are used only for serving specific routes like /a or may be subdomains like {abc}.xyz.com

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to trick it by messing with the headers. The other option is to using a reverse proxy like nginx in front of your node.js app, which redirects based on domain but I'd imagine nginx uses the same headers as express to determine the domain.

Comment: To answer your edit, if you want to restrict domains to certain users then you need proper security - https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html

Comment: I don't want to restrict domains to certain users, I just want them to route to specific endpoints only.

Comment: You could use the same approach as above, and redirect if the host doesn't match a host you want to serve that route to, but again it would be possible to get around by changing the headers if you really wanted to. Beyond that, I'm not sure I'm afraid.